# Не могу "достучаться" до контейнера в minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Информация о Pod

```
kubectl describe service short-app-port

Name:                     short-app-port
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   component=frontend
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 component=frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.106.48.157
IPs:                      10.106.48.157
Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31202/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.25:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Информация о Service

```
kubectl describe service short-app-port

Name:                     short-app-port
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 component=frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.106.48.157
IPs:                      10.106.48.157
Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31202/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.25:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

IP minikube

```
minikube ip

192.168.49.2
```

POD YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: short-app
  labels:
    component: frontend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "500m"
```

Service YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: short-app-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31202
  selector:
    component: frontend
```

При попытке перейти на GET http://192.168.49.2:31202/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]